# How to make calls from a Background Service?

Tags: android, service, background, call

i am new to android please help.
I tried using this code...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
startActivity(intent);
```

didn't work: it stopped abruptly.
i mentioned the necessary permissions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please provide more details so that we can help you with your problem. See also [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

You will get context from service `onStart()` Method. InPlace of `Context`, can use `getApplicationContext()`